# WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED?

Tags: java, matlab, jetty

I am scripting COMSOL (a physics simulation software) with MATLAB. My loop is pretty huge, running 8000 simulations. I encounter the following problem.

```
>> fig2b
Error using fig2b (line 17)
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.APIEngine.runMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.comsol.clientapi.engine.APIEngine.runMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.comsol.clientapi.impl.SolverSequenceClient.runAll(Unknown Source)

2014-05-10 22:18:37.692:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED qtp633622505{8<=5<=6/254,5}: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.doStop(QueuedThreadPool.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStop(AggregateLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory.doStop(WebSocketClientFactory.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at com.comsol.client.interfaces.v.onClose(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.closeIn(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014-05-10 22:18:37.693:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory@4af2aad3: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.doStop(QueuedThreadPool.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStop(AggregateLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory.doStop(WebSocketClientFactory.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at com.comsol.client.interfaces.v.onClose(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.closeIn(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Seeing the line `2014-05-10 22:18:37.692:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED qtp633622505{8<=5<=6/254,5}:`, I guess this is somehow caused by running too many simulations in one go. Hence, I tried running the 8000 simulations separately in 4 runs, with each run containing 2000 simulations. Then, *sometimes* a run is *successful*, but *sometimes* it *fails* halfway with the same error! **What confuses me is that I have NOT touched the code after it fails. Then, I re-run it, it works!**

According to the observations above, I believe this has nothing to do with COMSOL, but rather it is related to java or jetty or something. Could the experts suggest me some possible solutions to or causes of this?

Comment: **ATTENTION:** I have NOT yet solved this problem with Dennis' answer. So any new answer is very much welcomed and will be awarded with a new bounty.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you ask for solutions or causes, I have no clue about the cause but I may have the solution.

#### From my experience usually these java errors occur in one of these situations:

1. Running code that takes a long time to execute
2. Using multiple matlab instances at the same time
3. Using graphic tools that are not that popular (like `visdiff`)

#### Here are the solutions that I found usefull:

**1. Ignore the error**: It may sound strange, but especialy when doing long calculations Java errors are often printed in red without interrupting the code. Basically just waiting till the code is finished and its results are saved is my preferred solution in this case. However, once you start using the UI to click or type, the red text may get really annoying so after the run is finished I typically restart matlab.

**2. Restart Matlab**: When I don't have something running, the problem occurs very infrequently. In this case I typically just restart which is usually sufficient to make the errors dissapear.

**3. Disable Java**: Though I have not been bothered enough by the errors yet to try this, it is of course possible to use Matlab without using Java. This can be achieved by callingh matlab with the `-nojvm` flag. If java is disabled, this should prevent any java errors. If they would still occur, the problem is probably in the external programs that you call.

**4. Catch the error**: Have not tried this for Java errors, but it may work. In general anything that interrupts the matlab code should be caught as an error. You can put a `try - catch` block in the most important loop and may be able to work despite the error. However, this is really a desperate measure and should be considered a last resort.

#### Conclusion

If you have the same kind of errors as me and running the same code twice does not reproduce them, just consider them a warning that can be ignored. Afterall, java is only used for the UI, not for the calculations. However, if you actually get stuck by them, probably it is time to send a support request to mathworks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did you encounter the exact same problem as me? My case runs for a long time, and usually, I have multiple MATLAB windows running in parallel.

Comment: I do not think I can ignore the error, as the error stops my script right away. Does "Disable Java" really work? I don't really dare to do that. If it does not work, how may I re-enable Java? Thanks!

Comment: @FarticlePilter It is pretty safe to try the flag, you don't really disable java in a matlab session and also don't change any saved settings, but you start matlab without starting java. In the worst case you can always just start matlab normally the next time and it will have java enabled again.

Comment: Seems that if I disable Java, the thing cannot be run at all. `Error adding plugins to the Matlab Java Path: Undefined variable "com" or class
"com.mathworks.jmi.ClassLoaderManager.getClassLoaderManager".
`

Comment: @FarticlePilter As you mentioned doing something 8000 times, I assumed they would be pure calculations (for which java typically is not required). It may be the case that you have some graphic stuff going on, that you don't really need. You could try disabling those lines of code. Otherwise I would guess that the error is not in Matlab but something called by matlab (did not experience this before). In this case catching the error might still work, or you should at least be able to pinpoint on which line the error occurs.